# How do I rearrange chunks of each string in a column of a Dask Series?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Here's an example series

```
msg
a-b-c-d-e
1-2-3-4-5
v-w-x123-y0-z
0-9-8-7-6
```

I need to rearrange the msg column from this 
`[0]-[1]-[2]-[3]-[4]` 
to this 
`[2]-[5]-[3]-[1]-[4]`
as an example a-b-c-d-e --> b-e-c-a-d

in normal python this is easy my function "rearrange" just needs to str.split() by "-" and reassemble

But I'm having trouble doing this with a dask series

When I do this:

```
chunks = messages.str.split("-")
```

chunks becomes a Series containing lists of strings
and attempting to index chunks indexes the series instead.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from defining a rearranging function, to be applied to each
element:

```
def myRearrange(tbl):
    return '-'.join([ tbl[i]  for i in [ 1, 4, 2, 0, 3 ] ])
```

Then:

- Split the source *Series* using ordinary *str.split*. The result is
  also a *Series*, each element containing a *list* - the splitting
  result (chunks of the original string).
- Apply to it the above function, converting each chunk list into
  a string of rearranged chunks.
- Call *compute()* to show the result.

The code to do it is:

```
messages.str.split('-').apply(myRearrange, meta=('txt', 'object')).compute()
```

The detail you probably missed is *meta* parameter, specifying the name
and type of the result. You can also pass `meta='object'`, to get a *Series*
with **no name**.

The result is:

```
0         b-e-c-a-d
1         2-5-3-1-4
2     w-z-x123-v-y0
3         9-6-8-0-7
```